# Insert PHP associative array to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 08/21/13
    [1] => 08/21/13
    [2] => 08/21/13
    [3] => 08/21/13
    [4] => 08/21/13
    [5] => 08/21/13
)
```

How can I insert it to a MySQL database?

Comment: Means you want to insert this `Array
(
    [0] => 08/21/13
    [1] => 08/21/13
    [2] => 08/21/13
    [3] => 08/21/13
    [4] => 08/21/13
    [5] => 08/21/13
)` inside table or the values of array?

Comment: i want insert value of array( 08/21/13 ) into column date in mysql table

Comment: Is serialize is not working for you?

Comment: @yayantritaryana Does using `for` and `foreach` loop is that hard?

Comment: Please explain exactly what you want to do in more detail. You are being too vague. HOW do you want it inserted? You just mentioned that the date must go into a date field. What other parameters are you looking to follow? Do the 0,1,2,3,4,5 IDs refer to the `id` field in the database???

Comment: I think you need to put in a bit more details of this issue. This question is bit ambiguous. Couple of things that I think needs clarification are:
1. All array elements are ought to be inserted in a single row or a multiple rows.
2. You need the values (if a single row) to go into a single column or multiple ones.
3. If multiple columns are they supposed to go to a mySQL datetime field or just a string.

PS: Well it is 1 more than a couple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl (your_date_column_name) VALUES "
         . "('" .implode("'),('", $your_array)."')";
```

[**MySQL Manual**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) says:

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows.
>   To do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed
>   within 
>       parentheses and separated by commas.

So, SQL becomes,

```
INSERT INTO tbl (your_date_column_name) 
VALUES('08/21/13'),('08/21/13'),('08/21/13')
     ,('08/21/13'),('08/21/13'),('08/21/13');
```

Comment: Can you please explain whats wrong with the answer ? If there is, something is wrong with your question too. Please explain the question instead...

Comment: You fed the help vampire.

Answer (score -1):

Using foreach
First store array to one variable

```
$a=array('08/21/13','08/21/13','08/21/13','08/21/13','08/21/13','08/21/13');
foreach($a as $key=>$value){
    $date=date_create($value);
    $date1=date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
    //Here Your Insert Query
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLENAME SET date='".$date1."'");
}
```